# How do I convert a list of chars to a string in purescript

Tags: arrays, string, purescript

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to write a function `List Char -> String` in Purescript.

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I'm new to Purescript and have been browsing documentation for a while now with no progress!

**Background information:** I am porting a simple function from Haskell to Purescript

```
generateId :: Int -> [Char]
```

This generates a String of specified length. It was quite easy to convert the code to use `List Char` operations (where `List` is from `Data.List` in Purescript). In Haskell `[Char]` is the same as `String` so no other processing is needed, however, I can't find a function to convert from `List Char` to a native `String` in Purescript!

<strike>My search lead me to `fromCharArray :: Array Char -> String` in `Data.String`, however I could not find a way to convert from `List Char` to an `Array Char`!</strike>

I could manually convert between them by folding over `List Char` and building an `Array Char` using `snoc`, but surely I must be missing an inbuilt solution for what seems like basic String manipulation in Purescript!

**Edit:** `fromList` works to convert from any `Unfoldable` (such as Arrays) to a `List`. Still leaving this question open in case there is a more idiomatic way of achieving this.

Comment: `Data.String.fromCharArray <<< Data.List.fromList` sounds pretty decent to me. `fromCharArray` is implemented in native JS with `array.join("")`.

Comment: Yup, I'll take that as the idiomatic way of achieving this. Thanks!

Comment: @stholzm you should post that as an answer since it resolves the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with your edit. `Data.String.fromCharArray <<< Data.List.fromList` sounds pretty decent to me. `fromCharArray` is implemented in native JS with `array.join("")`.

**Update:** `fromList` is deprecated now - use `toUnfoldable` instead

Answer (score 2):

[*Updated Jan 2021*]

In PureScript 0.13.8:

```hs
import Prelude 

> import Data.Array (toUnfoldable)
> import Data.String.CodeUnits (fromCharArray)
> fromListChars = fromCharArray <<< toUnfoldable
> fromListChars ['2', '0', '2', '1']
"2021"

> fromListChars []
""
```