# How do I convert a string to a list of chars in purescript?

Tags: string, purescript

I have searched [pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=String+-%3E+List+Char), only two of them seems matchs well :

- charList from purescript-optlicative (module: Node.Optlicative.Internal)
- toChars from purescript-yarn (module: Data.String.Yarn)

And both `yarn` and `optlicative` is not available with psc-package (using psc-package 0.4.0 and `{"set": "psc-0.12.0", "source": "https://github.com/purescript/package-sets.git"}` )

Related question: [How do I convert a list of chars to a string in purescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565039/how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-chars-to-a-string-in-purescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first convert to `Array Char` via [`toCharArray`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-strings/4.0.0/docs/Data.String.CodeUnits#v:toCharArray), then convert to list:

```
import Data.List as List
import Data.String.CodeUnits as String

...

List.fromFoldable $ String.toCharArray "abcd"
```

**NOTE:** as of `purescript-strings` v4.0.0, `toCharArray` is exported from `Data.String.CodeUnits`, but before that it was in `Data.String`. Adjust according to the compiler/library version you're using.

Incidentally: are you sure you need a list and not an array? Lists are way less idiomatic in PureScript than in Haskell. Arrays are way more common.

Comment: this piece of code not works for me, could you please add the `import` sentence also?

Comment: Ok, I have added the `import` lines. However, if you require this high level of guidance, I suggest you ready some tutorials and work your way through some examples first, before writing your own code.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm going to have to write an answer instead of a comment to the previous answer because I don't yet have 50 reputation points. 50 reputation points are required before I can comment.*

To convert a string to a list of characters, you can use the following code:

```
import Data.String.CodeUnits (toCharArray)  --from package purescript-strings@4.0.0
import Data.List (fromFoldable, List)
import Data.Function ( ($) )                --from package purescript-prelude@4.0.1

convertStringToListOfChars :: String -> List Char
convertStringToListOfChars str = fromFoldable $ toCharArray str
```

---

From the REPL, using it gives the following result:

```
> convertStringToListOfChars "abcde"
('a' : 'b' : 'c' : 'd' : 'e' : Nil)
```